# brainfuck intepreter printing out wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, brainfuck

I recently decided to try to code "yet another" brainfuck interpreter, but I have a problem. It prints out the wrong numbers, when it should put our hello,world!. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance! I cannot figure out why it's doing this. Please help! I am only a beginner. Sorry for the bad coding style, but please don't change the whole thing. I would rather recieve tips.

```
from copy import copy
import sys

def brainfuckintepreter(program):
    # find pairs of brackets
    brackets = {}
    bbrackets = {}
    def findmatchingclosingbracket(ctr):
        level = 0
        if program[ctr] == '[':
            while True:
                if program[ctr] == '[':
                    level += 1
                elif program[ctr] == ']':
                    level -= 1
                if level == 0:
                    return ctr
                    break
                ctr += 1

    def findmatchingopeningbracket(ctr):
        level = 0
        if program[ctr] == ']':
            while True:
                if program[ctr] == '[':
                    level -= 1
                elif program[ctr] == ']':
                    level += 1
                if level == 0:
                    return ctr
                    break
                ctr -= 1
    """
    ctr = 0
    for a in program:
        if a == '[':
            f = copy(findmatchingclosingbracket(ctr))
            brackets[ctr] = f
            bbrackets[f] = ctr
        ctr += 1

    print(brackets)
    print(bbrackets)
    """
    # running the program
    tape = [0] * 3000
    pointer = 1500
    counter = 0
    results = ""
    valid = True
    while counter != len(program) and valid:
        a = program[counter]
        # move right
        if a == '>':
            if pointer == len(tape) - 1:
                tape.append(0)
            pointer += 1
        # move left
        elif a == '<':
            if pointer == 0:
                raise ValueError("On index ", counter, ", the program tried to move to -1 on the tape")
                valid = False
                return valid
            else:
                pointer -= 1
        # increment
        elif a == '+':
            if tape[pointer] == 255:
                tape[pointer] = 0
            else:
                tape[pointer] += 1
        # decrement
        elif a == '-':
            if tape[pointer] == 0:
                tape[pointer] = 255
            else:
                tape[pointer] -= 1
        # output character
        elif a == '.':
            t = chr(tape[pointer])
            results += t
            print(t, end='')
        # input character
        elif a == ',':
            tape[pointer] = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
        # opening bracket
        elif a == '[':
            if tape[pointer] == 0:
                pointer = findmatchingclosingbracket(pointer)
        # closing bracket
        elif a == ']':
            if tape[pointer] != 0:
                pointer = findmatchingopeningbracket(counter)
        counter += 1
        """
        for b in tape:
            if b != 0:
                print(b)
        """





brainfuckintepreter('++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.')
```

---

Edit:

I changed my code after some revisions, but same problem.

Comment: At a glance, you never enter those loops when handling brackets. The condition `while level > 0` is false if you start from `level = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops are the problem.

```
level = 0
while level > 0:
    ...
```

That loop will never be entered. The condition is immediately false (you're setting level to 0, right before checking if it is greater than 0).

You could change that to a `do..while` loop instead of a `while` loop (make a `while true` loop and check the condition at the end to decide whether to break out of the loop or not) and start checking at the current pointer position (include the current `[` or `]`), not at the next character after it.

Also here:

```
if tape[pointer] == 0:
        pointer = findmatchingclosingbracket(pointer)
```

you should be passing and updating the program counter, not the tape pointer on the second line. And likewise for the other one just below it.

Comment: Hi, I fixed that. Do you know why it is printing out the wrong values?